# Showing a window over the curent one in qt from necessitas

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I'm using Necessitas to compile and run my QT apps on Android. If I'd like to show another window over the Main Wondow,  I would create an UI file from QT Creator, which also will create a class. Then, I would create an instance of that class, and finally call the `exec()` member function.

However, in Necessitas QT Creator, the compiler tells me that the memeber function `exec()` doesen't  exist. If I try using the `show()` member function, nothing happens. Also , If I hide the Main Window, the program exits.

So ,what can I do to show the other Window that I created with QT Creator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstackedwidget.html

This is essentially a layout that behaves like a tabbed/paged widget but it doesn't show any tabs.  This should get you what you want.